# Riesz's lemma on invisible points

Tags: real-analysis

Let us define a point $x_0\in[a,b]$ as *invisible from the right* for a function $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ when $\exists\xi\in(x_0,b]:$ $\max\{g(x_0^+),g(x_0),g(x_0^-)\}<g(\xi)$, and as *invisible from the left* when $\exists\xi\in[a,x_0):$ $\max\{g(x_0^+),g(x_0),g(x_0^-)\}<g(\xi)$.

I know [Riesz's lemma](http://librarum.org/book/10022/164) stating that

> For any continuous function $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ the set of the points invisible from the right is open in $[a,b]$ and therefore is the union of countably many open disjoint intervals $(a_k,b_k)$ (where one of the set can be of the form $[a,b')$), such that $g(a_k)\leq g(b_k)$.
>
> Analogously, the set of the points invisible from the left is open in $[a,b]$ and therefore is the union of countably many open disjoint intervals $(a_k,b_k)$ (where one of the set can be of the form $(a',b]$), such that $g(a_k)\geq g(b_k)$.

I read in Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа* ([p. 329 here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) that Riesz's lemma can be generalised to apply to any function $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ only having step discontinuities, but it does not give a proof.

I know that a monotonic left, or right, continuous function is the sum of a continuous function and a step function, but I am not sure we can use that to prove the generalisation of Riesz's lemma and I have not been able to use it. Could anybody give a proof of this very interesting lemma (which Kolmogorov-Fomin's use to prove Lebesgue's theorem on the derivability almost everywhere of a monotonic function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$)? I must stress that Kolmogorov-Fomin's says that Riesz's lemma can be generalised without explicitly stating any requirement of monotonicity for $g$, but I would not be amazed if it were necessary, since it is used to prove Lebesgue's theorem, as I said. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $\max\{g(x_0^+),g(x_0),g(x_0^-)\}<M$ is equivalent to: $x_0$ has a neighborhood in which $g<M$. All points of this neighborhood also satisfy this inequality, which implies that the set on which the inequality holds is open.

The set of points invisible from the right can be written as 
$
\bigcup_{\xi\in (x_0,b]} A_\xi 
$
$$A_\xi=\{x\in [a,\xi): \text{$x$ has a neighborhood where } g <g(\xi)\}$$
Each $A_\xi$ is open in the subset topology of $[a,b]$. Therefore, the union is open.

---

The inequality between $g(a_k)$ and $g(b_k)$ need not hold when $g$ is discontinuous. 
Consider this function: $$g(x)=\begin{cases}2x\quad & x\in [0,1] \\ x-1\quad &x\in (1,2]\end{cases}$$ The visible points from the right are precisely $\{1,2\}$. So, $(1,2)$ is an invisible interval. But $g(1)>g(2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Elegant proof based on topology. Analogously, I'd say that the open set $\bigcup_{\xi\in[a,b]}$ contains all and only the points invisible from the left. Just one thing remains to proof: why $g(a_k)\leq g(b_k)$ for the disjoint intervals $(a_k,b_k)$ composing the set of the points invisible from the right and $g(a_k)\geq g(b_k)$ for the disjoint intervals $(a_k,b_k)$ composing the set of the points invisible from the left...

Comment: Ah, that part. That part actually isn't true as stated. Consider this function: $g(x)=2x$ on $[0,1]$ and $g(x)=x-1$ on $(1,2]$. The visible points from the right are precisely $\{1,2\}$. So, $(1,2)$ is an invisible interval. But $g(1)>g(2)$. One problem is that the visibility only takes into consideration the maximum $\max\{g(x_0^+),g(x_0),g(x_0^-)\}$, so it's impossible to infer much information about $g(x_0)$ specifically. I don't see how to adjust this claim so that it becomes true.

Comment: Then Kolmogorov-Fomin's proof of Lebesgue's theorem on the derivability almost everywhere of a monotonic function is probably wrong because it doesn't apply Riesz's lemma to a monotonic function $f$: it applies it to $f(x)-Cx$ where $f$ is non-decreasing. Thank you so much again!

Comment: I've noticed that the English translation "Introductory Real Analysis" shows an inequality different from the Russian original text and posted a different question about the inequality, which seems to me worthy a different thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997248/property-of-intervals-of-invisible-points